# SQL won't print out my variable

Tags: sql, debugging, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, dynamic-sql

I'm working with a SQL stored procedure and dynamic SQL. When I try to debug everything works fine, up until when I'm printing my @columnName.

this is the part of the code that's causing trouble:

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @columnName NVARCHAR(250)
SELECT @query = 'SELECT myTable.value FROM myTable WHERE myConditions'
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @query, N'@columnName NVARCHAR(30) OUTPUT', @columnName OUTPUT
    PRINT N'query='+@query
    set @query = ''
    PRINT N'query after reset='+@query
    PRINT N'columnName='+@columnName
    PRINT N'any other message'
Select @query = 'SELECT myValues AS '''+@columnName+''',
                 FROM myTable2
                 WHERE myConditions';
EXEC(@query);
```

This is the output messages:

```
query=SELECT myTable.value FROM myTable WHERE myConditions
query after reset=

any other message
```

So, where is my `columnName=` output?

**EDIT**

*SQL Version:* Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64) 
    Feb 10 2012 19:39:15 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using....

Comment: Added the version under "EDIT"

Comment: Added the appropriate **tag** `sql-server-2012` - that's where you should specify these kinds of things....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it.

Turns out that if I add something with null, the result will be null. So if I add `'string to be printed'+NULL` then nothing will be printed. Now I just have to figure out why the heck my variable doesn't have a value ^^ Wish me luck!

Answer (score 9):

Add SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF to the beginning of your process to allow the rest of the statement to print if there is a NULL value passed.

Comment: Awesome...just what I was after. Thanks.

Comment: Didn't know this existed. Thanks